# firebase and auth property does not exist in Ionic and Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating user-based content and button show using *ionic 5* and the *firebase* app.
I am going through on post and implement it in my application.

I and using :
 `"firebase": "^8.1.1",`   `"@angular/fire": "^6.1.3",`

Now I got errors in `auth()` and `firestore()`

> auth error is : Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof import
> (TS-2339)  AND firebase error is - Property 'firestore' does not exist
> on type 'typeof import

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
    import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
    import "firebase/auth";
    import "firebase/firestore";
     
    @Component({
      selector: "app-places",
      templateUrl: "./posts.page.html",
      styleUrls: ["./posts.page.scss"],
    })
    export class PlacesPage implements OnInit {
      constructor() {}
      //firestore = firebase.firestore();
      public isAdmin = false; 
      ngOnInit() {


    //Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof import
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
              if (user) {
                firebase


                  .firestore()    //Property 'firestore' does not exist on type 'typeof import
                 

 

    .doc(`s/${user.id}`)
                      .get()
                      .then((userProfileSnapshot) => {
                        this.isAdmin = userProfileSnapshot.data().isAdmin;
                      });
                  }
                });
       
        }
       }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show which version of the firebase module you're using.  It will be in your package.json.

Comment: @DougStevenson I update question. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Please review the documentation for [importing Firebase SDKs using a module bundler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize).  Starting with Firebase SDK version 8.0.0, you now must import like this:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

Notice that `* as` is no longer part of the import in this version.